# Gradle 7 equivalent of Gradle 5 declaring of dependency

Tags: gradle

what is right equivalent of multiproject (java projects) build.gradle setup for this dependency?

Gradle 5: compile project(path: ":foo", configuration: "runtime")

After gradle 7 runtime configuration is deprecated, also as compile, so need to refactor this dependency.

My opinion is

Gradle 7: implementation project(path: ":foo", configuration: "runtimeElements")

but i dunno, is it right?

Comment: What happens when you try that? Also, can we get a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi Robert, when i try line code with compile, it doesnt work, because gradle 7 make it deprecated(and configuration runtime deprecated too). Cant provide more info about gradle. But pretty sure it is enough to provide modern equivalent to this line. Just wanna the same result as before